# How to get the specific value from object using object[]Index for GetValue()?

Tags: c#

I have three values in this object `propValue`. The below code gives me all the value by looping through my result.

How can I get the value by passing `object[]Index` as second parameter to `prop.GetValue`?

The result has a bool,object,string in it. That is why I need to get a specific value.

```
Type myType = result.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
tring str = "";
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{ 
    object propValue = prop.GetValue(result,null); 
}
```

Comment: in your code the propValue just keeps the prop of last loop step.

Comment: Is `propValue` is `object[]` ? Then simply cast `((object[])propValue)[x]`.

Comment: object propValue = prop.GetValue(result, ((object[])propValue)[1]); ???

Comment: Please, add your the code for the class of the result and what are you expecting to do in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

If all properties are of type `object[]`, then:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in result.GetType().GetProperties())
{ 
    // get object[] {bool, object, string} at once 
    var propValue = (object[])prop.GetValue(result,null);
    var index1 = (bool)propValue[0];
    var index2 = propValue[1];
    var index3 = (string)propValue[2];
}
```

If you have different properties, then you can [check their types](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zv7cvW).

Testing for `object` is tricky, because all types are objects (inherited from `Object`). You do not need to test for it, but assume it, when other tests failed:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in result.GetType().GetProperties())
{ 
    var propValue = prop.GetValue(result,null);
    if(propValue is string)
    {
        // do something with string
        continue; // to skip checking for other types
    }
    if(propValue is bool)
    {
        // do something with bool
        continue;
    }
    // do something with object
}
```

Instead of `continue` you can use `else if` pattern.

Comment: ERROR : (object[])prop.GetValue(result, null) Cannot cast 'prop.GetValue(result, null)' (which has an actual type of 'bool') to 'object[]' object[]

Comment: That explains why `prop.GetValue(result, new object[] {0})` wouldn't work. What properties has `result` type? Perhaps you could search for them [by name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx)?

Comment: It works for string and bool. But when checking for val is object, it returns object when it is string as well.

Comment: So you don't have indexed properties at all? See edit.